# Are there levels of cointegration?

Tags: correlation, cointegration

I've seen someone describe two timeseries as being highly or not very highly cointegrated much the same as you'd describe two timeseries as being highly or not so highly correlated. I don't believe that one can define levels of cointgeration like this. If I do an ADF tets on two timeseries I'll get a p-value which indicates the likelihood of cointegration which i don't think can be considered a "level" of cointegration in the same manner as correlation. Am I correct on this - that coientegration is more of a yes|no value than a level?

Answer (score 2):

Cointegration is a yes/no phenomenon. Either it is present or it is absent. Either there are fewer common stochastic trends than there are series (thus presence of cointegration) or there are as many (absense of cointegration).

On the other hand, the speed of adjustment between the cointegrating series is a continous variable. The coefficient in front of the error correction term (or the coefficient vector in front of error correction terms, if there are more than one) quantifies the speed of adjustment. You may have series that coverge very fast after any deviations (the magnitude of the coefficient(s) will be large) but you may also have series that wonder off and return to equilibrium slowly (the magnitude will be low).

Comment: So, in summary, whether or not something is cointegrating is yes|no but the time between cointegrating and non-cointegrating phases will vary - sometimes short (fast convergence) and sometimes long (slow convergence). Correct? -- Thanks

Comment: No, there are no phases. Cointegration is a feature, a characteristic but not a state or a phase. What I wanted to say is, shocks to the system will not be of the same size each time. If a few large shocks happen to push the system further away from equilibrium, then the speed of the error correction mechanism will be relatively easy to observe. Differences between speeds in different systems will be more apparent when systems are further away from equilibrium than when they are close to equilibrium.

Comment: Re phases. As per my understanding a time series may be cointegrating for a period of time and then not cointegrating for a period of time ... yes? (that's what I mean by phase) Does this relate to the "shocks" you describe above?

Comment: There are all kinds of weird data in the world. However, it is common to break the data into periods of relative stability. For example, if you have 1000 observations on a variable and the first 500 look stationary but the following 500 look nonstationary, you would prefer to break the sample into two subsamples and analyze the behaviour of the variable separately in the two subsamples. The standard of cointegration modelling assumes the characteristics of the system do not change within the sample. Thus the series either are cointegrated or not cointegrated the whole time within the sample.

Comment: Textbook examples are about whole-time cointegration, not occasional cointegration.

Comment: In the case of two stocks/bonds. One might ask if the two series are cointegrating over the last six months and then re-ask that question every day/week/month. If you're wanting to make trading decisions based on whether or not two instruments are cointegrating then your sample may be the most recent N days/weeks/months. This is a little off-topic re my original question which you very thoroughly answered.

Comment: That makes sense. (Was there meant to be a question in there?)

Comment: No question, just my train of thought to make sure I understand the subject and assuming if I said something incorrect that I'd be corrected. Thanks again for your feedback